# Display Dynamically Added Contacts through VFP on another VFP

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I have a VFP here that has the ability to add/remove rows of Contacts. 
After I click 'Save Contact', I am redirecting the page to a PDF (VFP) that should display the Contacts that were added. 
However my table has blank data. Can some one please assist?

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" Controller="wrapperClassAddContacts" renderAs="PDF" >   
        <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="You added these Contacts">
                <table border="2px">
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                       </tr>
                  <apex:repeat value="{!contactList}" var="rec" >
                       <tr>
                            <td>{!rec.con.FirstName}</td> 
                            <td>{!rec.con.LastName}</td>
                            <td>{!rec.con.phone}</td>
                       </tr>
                  </apex:repeat>
                </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

// Add Contacts

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassAddContacts">
            <apex:form >

                <apex:pageBlock id="BlockId" >
                  <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
                  <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                   <apex:commandButton value="Save Contact" action="{!saveContact}" reRender="BlockId"/>
                  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="contact" id="table">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                        <!-- This is our selected Boolean property in our wrapper class -->
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!contact.selected}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <!-- This is how we access the contact values within our cContact container/wrapper -->
                    <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.FirstName}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.LastName}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Email}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Phone}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Admin1">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Py_Admin__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Admin2">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Sy_Admin__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Primary Tech">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Py_DTP__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Secondary Tech">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Sy_DTP__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Enquiry Contact">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.EC__c}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Billable Contact">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.BC__c}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Add/Remove Contact">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!addContact}" Rerender="table" />
                    <apex:CommandButton value="Remove" action="{!removeContact}" Rerender="table" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

// Controller

```
public class wrapperClassAddContacts {
    public List<wrapContact> contactList {get; set;}
    public Contact con {get;set;}
    public integer rowIndex {get;set;}


    public wrapperClassAddContacts () {
      rowIndex =0;
      contactList = new List<wrapContact>();
      Contact Cont = new Contact();
      contactList.add(new wrapContact(Cont));

    }
    Public PageReference addContact(){
      rowIndex += 1;
      Contact con = new Contact();
      contactList.add(new wrapContact(con));
      return null; 
    }

    Public void removeContact(){
      contactList.remove(rowIndex);
      rowIndex -= 1;   
    }


public PageReference saveContact() {
    boolean emailexists = false;
    Map<String, Contact> contactEmailMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
    List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
    list<string> minOnemaxTwoDSA = new list<string> ();

    for(wrapContact cCon: contactList) {
        if(cCon.selected == true){ 
           if(contactEmailMap.containsKey(cCon.con.Email)) {
                cCon.con.Email.addError('Another Contact has same email address');
                emailexists = true;
            } else {
                contactEmailMap.put(cCon.con.Email,cCon.con);
            }
        }    
    }

    selectedContacts.addAll(contactEmailMap.values());

    if(emailexists ==false && selectedContacts.size() > 0  ){
            insert selectedContacts;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Contact Saved succesfully'));
            contactList=null;
    }else{
        if(selectedContacts.isEmpty()){
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please Select atleast one contact'));
        }
   }        

    PageReference displayContactsPage = Page.DisplayContacts;
    displayContactsPage .setRedirect(true);
    return displayContactsPage ;


}

    public class wrapContact {
      public Contact con {get; set;}
      public Boolean selected {get; set;}
      public Boolean isDSA {get;set;}

        public wrapContact(Contact c) {
          con = c;
          selected = false;

        }
    }
}
```

// the PDF that is rendered

[image]

Comment: so, you have two VFP sharing the same controller? If yes, when the second (PDF) VFP is rendered, it will instantiate a brand new instance of the controller and needs to fetch the contacts -- adding them to the `contactList` variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things you have to fix it.

1) If you want to share variables between two VF pages you have to use `.setRedirect(false);`

**If setRedirect = true**

> A redirect is performed through a client side redirect. This type of
>   redirect performs an HTTP GET request, and flushes the view state,
>   which uses POST

**If setRedirect = false**

> The redirect is a server-side forward that preserves the view state
>   if and only if the target page uses the same controller and contains
>   the proper subset of extensions used by the source page.

2) After inserting the contacts you are making the `contactList=null;`. Remove it.

3) You are using `reRender="BlockId"` which is not required here as you are re-directing to a new page.

Updated Code

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassAddContacts">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="BlockId" >
            <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save Contact" action="{!saveContact}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="contact" id="table">
                <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                    <!-- This is our selected Boolean property in our wrapper class -->
                    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!contact.selected}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <!-- This is how we access the contact values within our cContact container/wrapper -->
                <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.FirstName}" required="true"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.LastName}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Email}" required="true"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Phone}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Admin1">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Py_Admin__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Admin2">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Sy_Admin__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Primary Tech">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Py_DTP__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Secondary Tech">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.Sy_DTP__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Enquiry Contact">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.EC__c}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Billable Contact">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!contact.con.BC__c}"/>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Add/Remove Contact">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Add" action="{!addContact}" Rerender="table" />
                    <apex:CommandButton value="Remove" action="{!removeContact}" Rerender="table" />
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

PDF Page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" Controller="wrapperClassAddContacts" renderAs="PDF" >   
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="You added these Contacts">
            <table border="2px">
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!contactList}" var="rec" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!rec.con.FirstName}</td> 
                        <td>{!rec.con.LastName}</td>
                        <td>{!rec.con.Email}</td>
                        <td>{!rec.con.phone}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class wrapperClassAddContacts {
    public List<wrapContact> contactList {get; set;}
    public Contact con {get;set;}
    public integer rowIndex {get;set;}


    public wrapperClassAddContacts () {
        rowIndex =0;
        contactList = new List<wrapContact>();
        Contact Cont = new Contact();
        contactList.add(new wrapContact(Cont));

    }
    Public PageReference addContact(){
        rowIndex += 1;
        Contact con = new Contact();
        contactList.add(new wrapContact(con));
        return null; 
    }

    Public void removeContact(){
        contactList.remove(rowIndex);
        rowIndex -= 1;   
    }


    public PageReference saveContact() {
        boolean emailexists = false;
        Map<String, Contact> contactEmailMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
        List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();
        list<string> minOnemaxTwoDSA = new list<string> ();

        for(wrapContact cCon: contactList) {
            if(cCon.selected == true){ 
                if(contactEmailMap.containsKey(cCon.con.Email)) {
                    cCon.con.Email.addError('Another Contact has same email address');
                    emailexists = true;
                } else {
                    contactEmailMap.put(cCon.con.Email,cCon.con);
                }
            }    
        }

        selectedContacts.addAll(contactEmailMap.values());

        if(emailexists ==false && selectedContacts.size() > 0  ){
            insert selectedContacts;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM,'Contact Saved succesfully'));
            //contactList=null;
        }else{
            if(selectedContacts.isEmpty()){
                ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'Please Select atleast one contact'));
            }
        }        

        PageReference displayContactsPage = Page.DisplayContacts;
        displayContactsPage.setRedirect(false);
        return displayContactsPage ;   
    }

    public class wrapContact {
        public Contact con {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public Boolean isDSA {get;set;}

        public wrapContact(Contact c) {
            con = c;
            selected = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Generated PDF

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the detailed and informative explanation.

Answer (score 1):

user4947, I think the issue may be that your wrapperClassAddContacts constructor sets the contactList variable to an empty list, without checking it first. Try changing your constructor to something like this:

```
public wrapperClassAddContacts () {
      if(rowIndex == null) rowIndex =0;
      if(contactList == null){
          contactList = new List<wrapContact>();
          Contact Cont = new Contact();
          contactList.add(new wrapContact(Cont));
      } 
}
```

...and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thankyou @Aubry for replying, and for your suggestion.